# Call a lambda function from a websub service as a callback url

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, netlify, jamstack

I want to get push notification when user uploads a new video in his/her youtube channel. I have set up a lambda function to trigger the netlify incoming webhook. And I have to call the lambda function as a callback url in the websub.

Now What will be the callback url to call the netlify function from a websub service?
"https://abc@netlify.com/" or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about your function endpoint, then it has the form
`https://your-site.netlify.com/.netlify/functions/<functionName>`

Where `functions/someFunction.js` would be the deployed function:

These endpoints can be found in the Netlify dashboard under the functions section of the site by clicking on the function.
[image]